# Renaming Multiple Files

Tags: windows, windows-7, file-rename, batch-rename

I have almost 2000 files which I need to rename.

The files are named in the following format: PART1#PART2#PART3.pdf

I would like to batch rename the files so that PART2 is moved before PART1 e.g. PART2#PART1#PART3.pdf

```
PART 1 = A random document reference e.g. 124244
PART 2 = A reference number e.g. 12-12434-A
PART 3 = A short description e.g. Part 1
```

The # symbol separates each of these parts.

Is there a simple utility which I can use to make this change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a batch file

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    cd /d "c:\where\thefiles\are"

    for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=#" %%a in ('
        dir /b /a-d *.pdf ^| findstr /r /b /e /i /c:"[^#][^#-]*#[^#][^#]*#..*\.pdf"
    ') do echo ren "%%a#%%b#%%c" "%%b#%%a#%%c"
```

What this code does is

1. Get the file list: a `dir` command asking for `.pdf` files in a bare format without the folders
2. Filters to only get the adecuated files: `findstr` command, searching for a regular expression that matches the beginning and end of the lines, ignoring case. The expression that is tested against the file names is : a non `#` character, followed by a sequence of non `#` or `-` characters (to avoid renaming the files twice), followed by a `#`, followed by a non `#` and a sequence of non `#` characters, followed by a `#` and any sequence of characters ending in `.pdf`
3. The `for` command splits the names using the `#` as token delimiter and for each one do the rename.

Rename operations are only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command

Comment: Please could you give me further details on how to use this approach. I have saved the above code as convert.bat and changed the directory path to the correct location of the folder. When I run the script though, nothing appears to happen and the file isn't renamed.

Comment: @user3220812, as indicated in the answer, files are not renamed. Rename operations will be shown in the console. `echo` needs to be removed. If you see no output to console, then your files do not follow the naming indicated in the question, that is: a sequence of numbers, #, a sequence of characters, #, another sequence of characters and a .pdf extension. Is this correct?

Comment: @NC ND - This is an example of one of the file names: 3326646#95-00770-REM#NULL.pdf. I have removed echo but the rename doesn't occur. I suspect it might be something to do with the dash in the file name (sorry I didn't mention this earlier).

Comment: @user3220812, after rereading your question, there is no place where it is stated that the part1 should be numeric. May fault. Answer changed

Comment: @user3220812, I have tested the code against your file name and it matches without problem (with a `.pdf` extension). The dash makes no difference.